# Is the GTKMM set_value_vfunc function a lie?

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gtktreeview, treemodel

I've been attempting to modify the contents of a custom tree view that inherits from `TreeModel` and `TreeSortable`.  However, the virtual function `set_value_impl` contains only an assert.  When I tried to look for example implementations, they all quote the GTKMM website which says "You can probably just implement this by calling `set_value_vfunc()`".

I have not found such function to exist anywhere in GTKMM.

Has anyone here run afoul of the GTKMM `TreeModel` when trying to modify the contents of a tree view?

Comment: Can you link to the GTKMM documentation you quote?

Comment: *Edit: I think I found it:
http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TreeModel.html#a26cf070eadb8e242bcf2b57f7e6d7d9e
Is there a reason you don't want to use ListStore or TreeStore?

Comment: The contents of the TreeView are the product of a SQLQuery, and for some reason we are relying on the TreeSort widget to do the sorting for us.  I begin to suspect that it is our implementation that is to fault, and not necessarily gtkmm.  

I realize that this is quite the edge-case.  I just wanted to know if anyone has had success with the set_value_vfunc function.

Comment: I'll be frank, but I can't find it. I even downloaded the gtkmm sources (3.0) and looked to see if Liststore or something was using it, and not a single one is. I can't find any reference to it, except on the net for this question and the docs (it seems to be used in a gtk library (libgda-uimm, but it is virtual). I think you might be right about your case being an edge one. Maybe look over the built-in models' source code to see how the gtkmm devs used the inherited classes.

Comment: That's what I suspected.  Could you submit your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As covered in the comments above, the `set_value_vfunc()` function simply does not exist.

Comment: I have corrected the documentation by removing that mention: http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkmm/commit/?id=e8229e67cb152ea2264bb60c5bd633243c3aef30

Comment: Here is how I implement that function in my database-backed TreeModel. It's not meant to be example code but it seems to work: http://git.gnome.org/browse/glom/tree/glom/mode_data/datawidget/treemodel_db.cc#n767